# How to Search Content in Views?

Tags: views

I have created a view to list all the contents I created. I need a search field in the view to search for contents. I tried the search module and when I search using one of the content names, it doesnt display the result.

Comment: The search module and Search form aren't linked with Views, they are separate modules. To use the Search form you have to have your content Indexed, otherwise the Search won't find it. Views will give you results without indexing. As mentioned in an answer you can use Filters in Views for the Title field and Expose it so users can enter keywords in it to search.

Answer (score 1):

views allow you to add some **"Filter criteria"** example:

> Add filter by content title then check **Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it**